# Send real time continuous log data to kafka and consume it

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have to analyse server logs of two different applications. The logs will generate continuously 24*7. I have credentials of the server where logs are generating. I need to get those logs data to kafka and extract some error information from those logs using python (by applying regex) and prepare a real time dashboard with the data I extracted. How can I ingest that log data which is generating continuously to kafka? Do I need to use NiFi? I am new to this scenario so if you understood my requirement above please give some Insights about how I can achieve that. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey, is Kafka only an option? If not, your specific use case can be solved easily with [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack). Logstash will allow you to ingest data/logs from multiple resources. With this, searching, parsing and dashboard will be easier to do - than using Kafka.

Comment: Hi Saurabh, Is it possible to handle continuously changing log data using ELK? I am new to this ELK concept. Is it free?

Comment: The logs are generated on append mode & Logstash just injest data from multiple sources, used for realtime data/log analysis. Elasticsearch(E), Logstash(L) & Kibana(K) are all open-source, though you need to maintain your own cluster, unless you want to use ELK as a service which is paid (from AWS and Elastic both).  You can read further about the deployment, use-case etc. on [elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co/) or [logz.io ELK guide](https://logz.io/learn/complete-guide-elk-stack/) . Hope this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For ingesting data from log files to Kafka, you can use Kafka Connect. Kafka Connect's most basic functionality is to copy data from external systems to Kafka or from Kafka to external systems.

Kafka connect is a java application hence doesn't require any external cluster to work (apart from the Kafka cluster where topic is present). The connectors are defined via a config file and hence is very simple to use with minimal code.

For transferring data from a file to Kafka, you can use and explore FileStream Connector of Kafka Connect - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/filestream_connector.html